# How to run insert query after submit form without refresh page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I'm using this to submit a form without refresh the page on submit but the problem is that I can't run the query to save values into my database

**This is my ajax code:**

```
function submit_form()
    {
        var name = $("#name").val(); 
        var email = $("#email").val(); 
        $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "submit.php",
                    data: "name="+name+"&email="+email,
                    success: function(response)
                        {
                            alert(response);
                        }
                    });

    }
```

**This is the code on my submit.php file:**

```
    if($_POST){
    $name=$_POST['name'];
    $email=$_POST['email'];

    mysql_query($wpdb->prepare(
  "INSERT INTO `wp_submitted_form` (`name`,`email`) values ('$name', '$email')"));

    }else { 
     echo 'nop!';
    }
```

If I remove,

```
mysql_query($wpdb->prepare(
      "INSERT INTO `wp_submitted_form` (`name`,`email`) values ('$name', '$email')"));
```

I can echo the variables

`echo $name;` and `echo $email;`

but when I try to save values on my database, I get no response and no values added into my database.

Any hints on what's the problem?

Comment: read about how to prepare and then execute. You should prepare with placeholders, then bind the values to those.

Comment: _AND_: mysql_*  is old, removed, unsecure. Use mysqli_*  or pdo

Comment: maybe you need to commit insert statement somewhere.

Comment: @yılmaz nop! Already tried that...